# How to tell the Websphere server that you should look for specific directory and make it available in the classpath?

Tags: java, websphere

I am using **Websphere application server 9**. I have some external files that are not supposed to be packaged as part of war file, but those files should be available for Websphere application server in its classpath. i.e the external files should be available in the classpath.

1. Can anyone tell which directory of Websphere will be available in classpath by default so that I can keep all those files there?
2. If the above option is not available, I will keep my external files in some location of Websphere server, but how to tell the server that "hey! you should look for specific directory and make it available in your classpath"?

Answer (score 0):

There are several directories which are on the classpath by default like `%WAS_ROOT%/lib/ext` or `%PROFILE_ROOT%/properties` however it is not recommended to use them for application specific files.

The recommended approach would be to create **Shared Library** where you could define directory where you want to store files that would be accessible and then associate it with the application.

Check these links:

- [how-create-shared-library-and-associate-it-application-server-or-enterprise-application](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-create-shared-library-and-associate-it-application-server-or-enterprise-application-websphere-application-server)
- [managing shared libraries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html)

Comment: I have configured as mentioned in the document, but getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException` with `(No such file or directory)`. The application is looking at the location :` `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/Cell01/awdcs_war.ear/awdcs.war/WEB-INF/classes/CustomerService/DataSourceConfiguration.xml` . Could you please tell me with what path and name the shared library be created for my scenario?

Comment: Is the application actually using the class loader for these files? A FileNotFoundException is typically not thrown by a class loader.

Comment: @Jarid, I think the exception is thrown when we try to access the application. The idea here is to load some configuration files that are out side  the war file by making an entry in web.xml . something like this: `<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:CustomerService/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>`

Comment: Try simple code fragment like this `getResourceAsStream("fDataSourceConfiguration.xml")` in your java class. I dont know how exactly `classpaht:CustomerService` is handled, as this is some spring notation.

Comment: @Gas , We are not loading the said file `DataSourceConfiguration.xml` explicitly, it should be taken care by spring framework itself. We did similar external configuration for `JBOSS 7.2 EAP` using `module.xml`, that worked. But I am struggling with Websphere to have similar sort of configuration.

Comment: @Ashok.N If you will use getResourceAsStream that will prove the the file is on the classpath and is correctly visible. Then it is up to you how to correctly configure spring to read it.

Comment: @Ashok.N as Jarid mentioned, exception suggest that spring config is incorrect and tries to use file path, not classpath.

Comment: @Jarid, Similar configuration worked for `JBOSS 7.2 EAP`, so there's no problem with Spring. I need to somehow make the Websphere to identify the external `DataSourceConfiguration.xml`, not sure how to do that..